# Dynamically adding JMX objects - client access notification

Tags: jmx

I'd like to expose the files in a directory via JMX objects. When a file is added or removed this should reflect in a new JMX bean.
But the beans should only be created if there is actually a client listing them with JConsole, i.e. the JMX beans should be lazyly created.
Is there a notification for client access?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, is there a way to detect when a remote client connects to an MBeanServer, then yes. The [JMXConnectorServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorServer.html) emits a notification when it opens a new connection from a remote client:

This is a summary of the published data:

- **Type**: jmx.remote.connection.opened
- **Event**: javax.management.remote.JMXConnectionNotification [source=<the object name of the JMXConnectorServer>][type=jmx.remote.connection.opened][message=Connection opened]
- **Message:**: Connection opened

This is what it looks like in jconsole:

[image]

Comment: Thx, I tried the code below, but got no notifications.
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

    JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL("rmi", null, 0);
    JMXConnectorServer connectorServer = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(jmxUrl, null, mbs);


    connectorServer.addNotificationListener(new NotificationListener()
    {
     
    public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback)
    {
    System.out.println("handleNotification");
    }
    }, null, new String("Conn"));

    connectorServer.start();